# Polymer element-defined styles not working

Tags: css, polymer, web-component

First of all, sorry for yet another post about this topic but I couldn't see anything that makes sense to me in polymer documentation and on stackoverflow.

I just want to attach style to my element.

From the documentation (https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/styling-elements.html and https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/styling.html#including-stylesheets-in-an-element)it should be straight forward.

```
 <polymer-element name="x-foo">
 <template>
 <style>
   x-foo div { ... }
 </style>
 ...
```

But it doesn't work as expected. If we define the style for an element, inside the element, it is not applied.

Here is the code:

```
  <polymer-element name="x-button" noscript>
    <template>

      <style>
        /* not working */
        x-button {
          background-color: green;
        }

        /* not working */
        x-button .hithere{
          display: block;
          min-height: 50px;
          background-color: red;
          margin: 20px;
        }

        /* not working */
        x-button .hitheretoo{
          display: block;
          min-height: 50px;
          background-color: blue;
          margin: 20px;
        }
      </style>


      <div class="hithere"></div>

      <template>
        <div class="hitheretoo"></div>
      </template>


    </template>

  </polymer-element>
```

And a live demo:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyZqMN

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`:host` selector](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/#toc-style-host) when styling an element from inside itself

```
<style>
  :host {
    background-color: green;
  }

  .hithere {
    display: block;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 20px;
  }

  .hitheretoo {
    display: block;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 20px;
  }
</style>
```

When you're styling from inside a custom element all selectors are already scoped to the element. By selecting `x-button` you are selecting any x-buttons that are *descendants* of this element, not the element itself. That also means you don't need to prefix selectors with the tag name to scope them; the shadow DOM provides scoping.

Comment: Thanks, issue was that I din't have a good understanding of what polyfill-next-selector was for and the "content" name was confusing to me since it is not the same thing as ::content.

Answer (score 1):

[ssorallen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368697/ssorallen) explained the css  issue very well and there is more. I couldn't get `:host` to work on it's own and depending on the browsers you will need to shim the Shadow DOM & add `polyfill-next-selector` styles.

Additionally, The element never gets registered because you have not used the `Polymer()` function inside the custom element (unless you chose not to add it in your code example). Here is a codepen of what I found to be [one possible solution](http://codepen.io/Nevraeka/pen/JoxmJd?editors=100).

The one thing I am still trying to figure out is the nested `<template>` issue. I can't pierce the shadow boundary with `::shadow` or `/deep/`. Might be a bug. I'll take a look when I get a few minutes.